# Where are the shapes in LibreOffice Draw?

Tags: libreoffice

I haven't been able to draw anything useful on LibreOffice Draw. Where are the different shapes to make diagrams? All I can find are basic shapes that I would find on Microsoft Word (squares, circles, stars, arrows, etc). Will I be able to make more elaborate diagrams like a data flow diagram or a basic UML diagram?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LibreOffice is a general-purpose drawing application and rather unsuited for diagramming and scientific drawing. It only -- as you have already seen -- provides basic shapes.

For diagramming, [GNU Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) is an excellent tool, but there are many other great programmes around.

EDIT: I also want to mention [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html): it scales very well to big graphs and can be run via Java WebStart. It has some really cool features.

Comment: Too bad to know that LibreOffice Draw won't do anything that is beyond basic shapes... that may be the reason why there isn't even a tag "libreoffice-draw" on this site. I will check your recommendations. Thank you.

Comment: "excellent tool" is not exactly what comes to mind when I think about GNU Dia. It's a productivity and user interface nightmare.

Answer (score 16):

If you're after a set of consistently styled isometric network equipment shapes (similar to the Visio ones) try these: http://www.vrt.com.au/downloads/vrt-network-equipment
(Creative Commons licensed, in the Fedora repos as and RPM as well).

Now also added to extensions.libreoffice.org and extensions.openoffice.org

[image: Sample of shapes]

Comment: After installing the extension, to actually use it, you need to go to the "Gallery" tab in the "Sidebar Deck" and look for categories that start with "VRT".

Comment: I came here exactly for @MichaelMandel 's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just find it in the bottom pane

If you didn't find it, just go to

**View > Toolbars > Drawing**

That's all..You will get it.

As usual, like Microsoft Office you will get in the respective menus. [If you still remember the old office menus instead of the new Ribbon interface]

Answer (score 2):

There is https://github.com/sschmidhuber/LibreSymbols. But it provides mostly symbols for electric/logic diagrams. In future it will also support eEPC diagrams. May be that's interesting for you or somebody else.

UML is not on the roadmap.

Comment: Good recommendation, by the way it is fully compatible with Libreoffice 6. I only missed digital logic gates

Answer (score -1):

Well they are here ;) So just add em ;)

http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/smart