# Using Libre Office Draw to draw UML class diagrams

Tags: libreoffice, diagram, uml, dia

I have been using "Dia" to draw UML class diagrams in Linux environments. However, it seems that Dia is not under active development, and its UI is not as good as LibreOffice Draw.

Could I also use Libre Office Draw to draw UML diagrams efficiently?

I could find some custom shapes from the following page.
http://www.lautman.net/mark/coo/index.html

However, I think these are just figures so they are not as useful as Dia UML class diagrams. So, I wonder what would be the best way to draw UML class diagrams using LibreOffice.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are already aware of what is available.

- Dia is recommended over LO Draw at: [Where are the shapes in LibreOffice Draw?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121400/where-are-the-shapes-in-libreoffice-draw)
- I recommended the www.lautman.net shapes in my answer at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/152625/is-there-a-uml-xshape-for-libreoffice/.
- One more link that may be helpful: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/52206/is-a-system-wide-uml-class-diagram-for-libreoffice-4432-available-somewhere/.